# C++ class building and running without calling parent constructor

Tags: c++

I have found a strange situation which I cannot explain. I have a parent class and base class. In the parent class's constructor, I define a local object (it's a complicated C apparatus - think an XML parser and processor). Then I created a child class, but in the child class constructor, I completely forgot to call the parent constructor. The result is that the program runs and all things seem well. The child class calls all parent class operations and everything seems to work... until the program crashes horrendously (talking about panic at the kernel level). I'm not sure at this point if this is the cause of the crash, but it might be.

What I am after is trying to understand how this is working (up until a point, perhaps). Am I being so insanely ridiculously lucky that the memory is lining up in respect to the local object?

Take a look at the simplified definitions to see what I mean

```
// header
class ParentClass
{
    private:
        OtherClass _complexObject;
    protected:
    public:
        ParentClass();
        virtual ~ParentClass();
        virtual void AddData(OtherClass *complexObject);
        virtual void DoStuff();
}

class ChildClass: public ParentClass
{
    private:
    protected:
    public:
        ChildClass();
        virtual ~ChildClass();
}

//source
ParentClass::ParentClass()
{
    _complexObject = create_complex_object();
}
ParentClass::~ParentClass(){}
void ParentClass::AddData(OtherClass *complexObject)
{
    add_data_to_object(complexObject, 12345);
}
void ParentClass::DoStuff()
{
    AddData(_complexObject);
}


BaseClass::BaseClass(){}
BaseClass::~BaseClass(){}

// at some point, BaseClass::DoStuff() is called...
```

Comment: Children will initialize their parents with default ctor if you don't do it explicitly

Comment: Are those "BaseClass" definitions at the bottom typos of ChildClass? Anyway, @AndyG is correct, you can see this by putting output in the ParentClass's constructor and watching it print out. If you make ParentClass's constructor private, in fact, your code won't even compile. It is very unlikely an XML parser/processor would be causing a kernel panic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Then I created a child class, but in the child class constructor, I completely forgot to call the parent constructor.

The reason this works and compiles is because the C++ language ensures that the objects in a hierarchy are initialized. In this case, the compiler sees that your derived ("child" in your terms) class doesn't call the base's ("parent") constructor... so the compiler does it for you.  Now, it can only do this if the base class has an accessible default constructor (a constructor that takes no arguments), which is also the case here.

If your base class didn't have a default constructor (that is, it only had constructor(s) that needed arguments), the compiler wouldn't know what to do on it's own and that would be a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

If the "complex object" have an default constructor is going to be initialized no matter what. Maybe down the line you are using a variable that basically have "garbage" and that is causing you problem.

Comment: Say what? Please clarify your statement.

Comment: @Matt Gallant gave you the more robust answer.

Comment: I did not need an answer. I was commenting on the quality of your post.